# How open this Christmas light plug to change fuse?

Tags: fuses, light, plug

I'm trying to get to the fuse in this plug (pictured below) and it looks like I'm going to break it instead. All the videos and instructions I've found show a different plug that it is very easy to open (slide something and there are the fuses). I don't have the instructions for this light star. This plug is different. I tried to push the hole with a screw driver and the blades for 120VAC but nothing. Any marks you see were made by me. I tried from the top with no luck either. Any ideas how to get to the fuse?

[image: plug]
[image: star light]

Comment: Doesn't look user-replaceable. Consider that if the fuse burned out, the light itself could itself be damaged and replacing the fuse wouldn't fix anything. Other Christmas lights have replaceable fuses since they are designed to be daisy-chained; this light is not.

Comment: It looks as though you would squeeze the two tabs together on the pin side then push the center piece out the back. Have you tried that already? Another possibility is that the plug had been running hot and the plastic parts have melted together. Then again the assembly might have been permanently sealed for safety. At some point you may just want to replace the whole plug with a new fused type. Also, per the other comment, you should first check the wired string and each bulb for any direct shorts, the fuse burned for a reason.

Comment: The plug is melted, why don't you just cut the wire and use another plug?

Comment: May I just add that it's a very pretty Christmas ornament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tab/snap that has to be released by putting something like a screwdriver through that slot. The top part will then pop out. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ITw_eWAQt84) is a (very blurry) video showing the procedure with a similar unfused male plug. If your screwdriver is too thick or otherwise not the right shape it may not work, so try another one. Looks like it's mashed up from using a fat screwdriver.

[image]

If you blew the fuse by plugging something that drew too much current into the female end then you have nothing to worry about, just replace the fuse or fuses with the exact equivalent type and rating. Otherwise there might be a problem somewhere in the light set.

Comment: I was able to open it with your instructions/video. There is no glass fuse though. Just the fusible wire. I'm replacing the whole plug. Thanks.

Comment: @Rodo Sounds like the prudent move. Were you able to find a plug with fuse built in? They're not so common in North America, AFAIK.

Comment: I haven't look too hard but when I did a few days ago I could not find it. I'm in no hurry though. The star belongs to my sister and she wants it fix for next XMAS.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a frame challenge than a real answer.

Was there an over-voltage applied to your Christmas light? (lightning nearby, voltage surge on mains, or plugging it into some higher voltage socket (220V for example)?)

If the answer is YES, then maybe (or maybe not) the light is still functional and changing the fuse is enough to make it work again.

If the answer is NO, then the fuse breaking is not the root of the problem, but just the consequence of some other problem (probably a short circuit, or near short circuit). If you change the fuse without solving the root problem first, you will just burn the new fuse. So there is no point in trying to replace the fuse before you identified and corrected the root cause.